# How to send image in mail body not like attachment in java

Tags: java, email

I am doing Java Web application, I am sending mails in that mail body i need to display image but when i send mail it takes image attachment i don't want to attachment  i need to show the image in body content can anyone please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @scary-wombat mentioned, you didn't add the first par. I suppose you meant to do:

```
        ...
        // add it
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // second part (the image)
        ...
```

You can also add a Content-Disposition header to the image part:

```
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, you must also move up the creation of multipart:

```
        ...
        // add it
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // second part (the image)
        ...
```

UPDATE 2:

Try this:

```
          BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
          messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
          // add it
         MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // second part (the image)
          messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

          java.io.InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/HappyBirthday.JPG");
         ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream, "image/jpg");
         System.out.println(inputStream);

          messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
          messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

          messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);

         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
         message.setContent(multipart);  
         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: HI, `javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
 java.io.IOException: javax.mail.MessagingException: No MimeBodyPart content` I got this exception i did with your code

Comment: I updated how i am added you people both code could you please tell me where did i mistake

Comment: @phani You create the html part and do nothing with it. you should add it to the multipart before you reassign the variable messageBodyPart (or, as suggested by ScaryWombat, use a second variable). In any case, both parts must be added to the multipart.

Comment: Hi, I am still getting same error can you please tell me

Comment: Thank you so much it's working you save my time thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code

```
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

// second part (the image)
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
```

you will see that you are re-initializing `messageBodyPart` whilst the `HTML` parts hasn't yet been added

I suggest that you use a different Object and then add both

```
// second part (the image)
messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
....
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
```