# include a file within email body in velocity spring

Tags: java, velocity

Whether it is possible to insert a file as a embedded object inside the body with icon in velocity spring mvc java. I don't want to attach the file instead it should be placed in the body of the mail in *.vm template.

For example

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1346-outlook-attachment-in-body-of-email.html

Comment: You want to place a file as plaintext in the email body? that seems like a very strange idea: the proper place is clearly in attachments.

Comment: @sjahan I need to place or  Insert Attachments In The Body Of Email Message. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1346-outlook-attachment-in-body-of-email.html

Comment: @bharati did you try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45559834/5860648 I guess it'll work even if it's not images.

Comment: @sjahan No.I have vm template. Within the same I have to place the file in body. If I do it as mention I am not sure it will be placed within vm template

Comment: @bharati, i found another interesting post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30351465/5860648 I think you must first understand the shape of an email (i'm not an expert on that part either), then once you know what you'll have to do, set it up nicely with velociy :)